# URL Routing in ASP.net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, url-routing

i use this code in Global.asax page for Map Page Route in asp.net 4

```
    protected void RegistreRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Lerning-browse", "Learning-CSharp", "~/CSharp.aspx");
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistreRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

When the user Enter *mysite.com/Learning-CSharp* in URL. MapPageRoute its working and get *mysite.com/Learning-CSharp* URL. but if user Enter *mysite.com/CSharp.aspx* in URL its Working and get *mysite.com/CSharp.aspx* in URL.

i want not get *mysite.com/CSharp.aspx* in URL. i want if user Enter *mysite.com/CSharp.aspx* in URL its convert to *mysite.com/Learning-CSharp*

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void RegistreRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}", new              
    System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}", new 
    System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));

    routes.MapPageRoute(
         "HomeRoute",
         "",
         "~/default.aspx"
     );
    routes.MapPageRoute(
    "Lerning-browse", "Learning-CSharp", "~/CSharp.aspx");
}

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegistreRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: its not working. i Enter mysite.com/CSharp.aspx in URL and not convert to mysite.com/Learning-CSharp

Comment: by using this code, users can not access your pages with .aspx urls, but I'm not sure if it is posible what you want,good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for IIS URL rewriting.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Something along the lines of the following should do it:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
            <match url="(.*)(\.aspx)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This'll need further modification if you also want to support querystrings.

Comment: i can not setting IIS. i use this in host and not access in setting

Comment: @shahinko I don't understand that comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

An easier process, if you only have one or two routes you need to manage, is to simply add them into your web.config file as hard coded redirects.

Something like:

```
<location path="CSharp.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/Learning-CSharp" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I've used this type of redirect on a number of lagacy websites, particularly when migrating to a new code-base; i.e. migrating from webforms to MVC.

Hope this helps.